# If cell begins with 'z' then 'Q' else 'A'

Tags: excel, vba

I want to check if the value of cells B5 to the last row in column B begins with a lowercase z.  If so I want to set value of column S for that given row to Q, if the value of column B begins with any other character I want the value of column S to be A.  Here's what I've tried that is not working...

```
Range("S5:S" & lRow).Formula = "=IF(LEFT(B5,1)=""z"",""Q"",""A""))"
```

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: the line doesn't execute, it breaks out of the sub.

Comment: What is the value of `IRow` when it breaks?

Comment: You have one too many `)` on the end.

Comment: @ScottCraner 34

Comment: damn those parenthesis!  Thanks Scott, now it executes but is returning Q for a value in my range that begins with a capital Z and I only want to return Q for a lowercase z.

Comment: Your formula needs a `LOWER` part. I think.https://support.office.com/en-us/article/lower-function-3f21df02-a80c-44b2-afaf-81358f9fdeb4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one too many ")", and you want to use EXACT().

Use:

```
Activesheet.Range("S5:S" & lRow).Formula = "=IF(EXACT(LEFT(B5,1),""z""),""Q"",""A"")"
```

[image]

Comment: Close Scott, but EXACT is acting like all or nothing.  My B column values will always contain more than a single character, I'm just trying to check for the lowercase z in the first position.

Comment: and the left inside the EXACT should only compare the first letter.

Comment: it does not.  it returns nothing, not a Q or an A.

Comment: got it.  'Range("S5:S" & lRow).Formula = "=IF(EXACT(LEFT(B5,1),""z""),""Q"",""A"")"' was the solution.

Comment: Is that not the exact formula that Scott provided?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
Range("S5:S" & lRow).Formula = "=IF(EXACT(LEFT(B5,1),""z""),""Q"",""A"")"
```

`Exact` allows you to compare two strings with Case sensitivity.

Answer (score -3):

the range "S5:S" is wrong
replace it with "S:S"

Comment: `Range("S5:S" & lRow)` is correct as long as `IRow` is not less than 1.

Comment: No, S5 is my starting cell.

Comment: @ScottCraner correct, and lrow is verified as not less than 1 earlier in the sub and I have other formula statements using it without a problem.